# Export View Controller Work to PDF

Tags: ios, iphone

I am new to iOS Development and have come to my final step in completing the app. The app is a monthly reporting app for a company. The user gets access to change the photo for each description of a job and have as many as there are needed for that month. My issue now is exporting all of the ViewController work to a pdf from the phone rather than him taking screenshots of everything. This is essential to the completion of the application.

Thanks to whoever can help me.

Answer (score 0):

See [the PDF drawing documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/2ddrawing/conceptual/drawingprintingios/GeneratingPDF/GeneratingPDF.html) for how to draw PDFs in iOS. It's a great API that's works off Quartz 2D. In fact, other than the functions to start and finish the PDF context, all the drawing code is the same as if you were using `drawRect`. Basically, you need to open a PDF context, start a new page, and draw your content into it. It will be saved to either a data object or a file, at which point you can [send the PDF as an email](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/mfmailcomposeviewcontroller/), upload it to Dropbox with the Dropbox SDK, [open it in another app](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/previewing-and-opening-documents-with-uidocumentinteractioncontroller/), etc.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks! I will figure out how to use it!